# Convert from MongoDB _id to string in C

Tags: c, mongodb

I want to use the mongodb _id attribute to guarantee uniqueness in a name.

```
mongo_cursor_init( cursor, &conn, &database );
bson_iterator iterator[1];

bson_find( iterator, mongo_cursor_bson( cursor ), "name" );
const char *filename = bson_iterator_string( iterator );

bson_find( iterator, mongo_cursor_bson( cursor ), "_id" );
const char *mongoid = bson_iterator_string(iterator);

char name[255];
strcpy(name,filename);
strcat(name,".");
strcat(name,mongoid);
```

However, the variable mongoid does not get populated correctly (at all...).  I'm not sure how to find the datatype of _id.  Has anyone done this before?  Thanks!

edit: i think the answer is in [here](http://api.mongodb.org/c/0.4/api/bson_8h.html), but not sure...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this helps somebody...

**Mongo _id to string:**

```
char mongoid[25];
bson_find( iterator, mongo_cursor_bson( cursor ), "_id" );
bson_oid_t *oid = bson_iterator_oid( iterator );
bson_oid_to_string(oid,mongoid);
```

**string to Mongo _id:**

```
bson_oid_t new_oid;
bson_oid_from_string(&new_oid,mongoid);
```

Answer (score 1):

You want `bson_iterator_oid()`--oid is for ObjectId.

You can get bytes out of that, and convert them to hex using a loop like (untested):

```
bson_find( iterator, mongo_cursor_bson( cursor ), "_id" );
bson_oid_t *oid = bson_iterator_oid( iterator );

char mongoid[25];
for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
  snprintf( mongoid, 2, "%02X", oid->bytes[i] );
}
```

Also, consider using `strncpy` and `strncat` with sane maximums--if the name field were 300 characters long, you'd have some unexpected behavior here.

Comment: Thanks, this was almost what I needed, and it sent me down the right path.

Answer (score 0):

If I had enough reputation points I would have added this comment on [@jacobra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/812335/jacobra)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11513168/13901111) to have the code working:

```
char mongoid[25];
bson_find( iterator, mongo_cursor_bson( cursor ), "_id" ); // not sure if this function actually exists or the user referred to bson_iter_find
const bson_oid_t *oid = bson_iterator_oid( iterator );
bson_oid_to_string(oid,mongoid);
```

Just added the const keyword before  `bson_oid_t *oid = bson_iterator_oid( iterator );`

It's also worth mentioning that I have not been able to find the function "bson_find", and one could use something like this:

```
bson_iter_t         Iterator; // to loop over the bson document 
if (!bson_iter_init(&Iterator, Document.GetDocumentStr())) // your document
        return;
while (bson_iter_next(&Iterator)) {
if (BSON_ITER_HOLDS_OID(&Iterator) && strcmp(Key, "_id") == 0)
// our key is the _id
        {       
            const bson_oid_t *oid = bson_iter_oid(&Iterator);
            bson_oid_to_string(oid, Data.Id);
        }
}
```

Useful links:

- [bson_iter_find](http://mongoc.org/libbson/current/bson_oid_t.html)
- [bson_oid_t example](http://mongoc.org/libbson/current/bson_oid_t.html)